# How to pick a photo contest?

Tags: competitions

Are there any established photo contests that are not either:

1. Organized (as opposed to endorsed or sponsored) by a photo equipment vendor
2. Pay-to-play
3. Exploitative i.e. require the submitter to assign commercial usage rights outside the scope of the competition.

Comment: How about the [photo.stackexchange weekly featured image contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest)? ;)

Comment: The title — "how to pick?" — seems on topic, but the body of the question seems to ask for a specific recommendation based on some already-decided rules for how to pick. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I participate in Gurushots, from time to time.
It's free, not endorsed by some company and everyone can vote.

Comment: I'm interested in something with more real-world recognition, like the Leica Oscar Barnack award but one that is not limited to professionals.